# Mount mdf file to sql server desktop edition

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to attach a `.mdf` file to a SQL Server Desktop Edition.

After reading [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325003) I connected to the database using the

```
osql -E -S servername\instancename
```

command.

I tried to attach the `.mdf` file with the following command

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'mydb', 
     @filename1 = N'C:\Backup\mydb.mdf', 
     @filename2 = N'C:\Backup\mydb.ldf'`
```

and then I get the following error.

> Msg 602, Level 21, State 50, Server serverName, Line 1
>   Could not fine row in sysindexes for database ID 5, object ID 1, index ID 1.

I don't really know what any of this means I have never used `osql` before.

Comment: You get that error when you try to connect, or you get that error when you try to attach? Where did the mdf file come from? Are you sure it's valid and that it was detached cleanly? What version of SQL Server did it come from? What version are you trying to attach it to (Desktop Edition hasn't existed in ~13 years IIRC)? Can you obtain a proper backup instead of the mdf file?

Comment: i get the error when i try to attach, the back up was created  by an the same edition of sql. sql server desktop 2000, yeah i know its old lol. the old computer has crashed so i cant make a new back up. i'm fairly confident that it is not corrupt.

Comment: Can you post the script you are trying to run for your the attach?

Comment: @Mike Desktop Edition was retired in 2000...

Comment: I made an edit the the post with the command I used to attach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is not a SQL Server 2000 database you are attempting to attach to SQL Server 2000. That appears to be a common cause of the error as indicated [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/msg-602-level-21-state-50-line-1/) also.

Can you attach this to SQL Server 2005 or 2008 Express and see what error message you get? Do you have access to the underlying database that your files are from?

I imagine if you attach this to SQL Server 2005 or 2008 you will be able to attach it unless there are other impediments to attach going on that that approach will reveal.